# Can I reposition an MKAnnotationView that's already been placed on a MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Every few seconds I'm retrieving an updated lat and lon for a real-world object that is in motion.  This object is represented on my MKMapView by an MKAnnotationView.

Is it possible to smoothly animate the object's movement from coordinate to coordinate, rather than remove its current MKAnnotationView and add a new one at the new coordinate?

I can think of several approaches in theory, I just don't have the chops to implement them by the end of this lovely Saturday.  So I am fine with any approach, however hacky, I just might need a bit of hand holding.

Thanks in advance for any help!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a try...have you added the `setCoordinate:` to the related annotation object and set the annotationView to allow dragging? If so, can you programatically set the coordinate and update it?